# Is there a way in javascript to find out how many times a certain string is in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that I want to find the number of string `'hello'` in it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand how this question is different [from your earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073157/can-you-use-javascript-search-on-an-array-as-well-as-a-string).

Comment: @patrick I mean this in the earlier one but I must not have specified well enough because I got answers that only returned the location of the first one in the array. The answers I got on this one are exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You may want to consider deleting that one if it didn't express your issue. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = 0;
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i] == 'hello') {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's an array of strings,

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; ++i) {
  if (stringArray[i] == "hello")
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And now for something completely <strike>different</strike> functional:

`var count = stringArray.filter(function(x) { return x == "hello" }).length`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=['no','hello',2,true,false,'hello','true','hello'];
if(arr.indexOf){
    var ax= -1, count= 0;
    while((ax= arr.indexOf('hello', ax+1))!= -1)++count;
}
alert(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
var count = stringArray.reduce(function(a,b){ return (b=='hello')?a+1:a},0)
```